# Dynamically search columns for given table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I need to create a search for a java app I'm building where users can search through a SQL database based on the table they're currently viewing and a search term they provide. At first I was going to do something simple like this:

```
SELECT * FROM <table name> WHERE CAST((SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<table name>') 
  AS VARCHAR) LIKE '%<search term>%'
```

but that subquery returns more than one result, so then I tried to make a procedure to loop through all the columns in a given table and put any relevant fields in a results table, like this:

```
CREATE PROC sp_search
    @tblname VARCHAR(4000),
    @term VARCHAR(4000)
AS
    SET nocount on
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
    INTO #tempcolumns
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tblname

    ALTER TABLE #tempcolumns
    ADD printed BIT,
        num SMALLINT IDENTITY

    UPDATE #tempcolumns
        SET printed = 0

    DECLARE @colname VARCHAR(4000),
        @num SMALLINT
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT MIN(num) FROM #tempcolumns WHERE printed = 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @num = MIN(num) 
            FROM #tempcolumns 
            WHERE printed = 0
        SELECT @colname = COLUMN_NAME 
            FROM #tempcolumns 
            WHERE num = @num
        SELECT * INTO #results FROM @tblname WHERE CAST(@colname AS VARCHAR) 
                    LIKE '%' + @term + '%' --this is where I'm having trouble
        UPDATE #tempcolumns
            SET printed = 1
            WHERE @num = num

    END

    SELECT * FROM #results
GO
```

This has two problems: first is that it gets stuck in an infinite loop somehow, and second I can't select anything from @tblname. I tried using dynamic sql as well, but I don't know how to get results from that or if that's even possible.

This is for an assignment I'm doing at college and I've gotten this far after hours of trying to figure it out. Is there any way to do what I want to do?

Comment: As an aside, don't ever say `VARCHAR` without specifying a length. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: I hit that problem earlier on where the size was declared as 1, but I fixed that in my now useless code. Let nobody else fall into that trap!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to only search columns that actually contain strings, not all columns in a table (which may include integers, dates, GUIDs, etc).
2. You shouldn't need a #temp table (and certainly not a ##temp table) at all.
3. You need to use dynamic SQL (though I'm not sure if this has been part of your curriculum so far).
4. I find it beneficial to [follow a few simple conventions](https://sqlblog.org/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist), all of which you've violated:

   - use `PROCEDURE` not `PROC` - it's not a "prock," it's a "stored procedure."
   - [use `dbo.` (or alternate schema) prefix when referencing any object](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).
   - wrap your procedure body in `BEGIN`/`END`.
   - use vowels liberally. Are you saving that many keystrokes, never mind time, saying `@tblname` instead of `@tablename` or `@table_name`? I'm not fighting for a specific convention but saving characters at the cost of readability lost its charm in the 70s.
   - don't use the `sp_` prefix for stored procedures - this prefix has special meaning in SQL Server. Name the procedure for what it does. It doesn't need a prefix, just like we know they're tables even without a `tbl` prefix. If you really need a prefix there, use another one like `usp_` or `proc_` but I personally don't feel that prefix gives you any information you don't already have.
   - since tables are stored using Unicode (and some of your columns might be too), your parameters should be `NVARCHAR`, not `VARCHAR`. And identifiers are capped at 128 characters, so there is no reason to support > 257 characters for `@tablename`.
   - [terminate statements with semi-colons](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons).
   - [use the catalog views instead of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views) - though the latter is what your professor may have taught and might expect.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SearchTable
    @tablename NVARCHAR(257),
    @term      NVARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @tablename + ' WHERE 1 = 0'; 

    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' 
      OR ' + c.name + ' LIKE ''%' + REPLACE(@term, '''', '''''') + '%'''
    FROM 
      sys.all_columns AS c
    INNER JOIN 
      sys.types AS t
      ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
      AND c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
    WHERE 
      c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@tablename)
      AND t.name IN (N'sysname', N'char', N'nchar', 
        N'varchar', N'nvarchar', N'text', N'ntext');

    PRINT @sql;

    -- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

When you're happy that it's outputting the `SELECT` query you're after, comment out the `PRINT` and uncomment the `EXEC`.

Comment: Wow, this is helpful. My SQL course was not very in depth, but you've given me excellent information. We weren't taught to do the things I'm trying to do, so Google has pretty much been my source for all of this. I just tried to use another temp table to create a table variable containing all the columns in the given table and I failed miserably. I'll give your code a shot. EDIT: It worked perfectly first time. Thanks so much! I'll put a link to this into my documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You get into an infinite loop because `EXISTS(SELECT MIN(num) FROM #tempcolumns WHERE printed = 0)` will always return a row even if there are no matches - you need to `EXISTS (SELECT * ....` instead

To use dynamic SQL, you need to build up a string (varchar) of the SQL statement you want to run, then you call it with `EXEC`

eg:

```
 declare @s varchar(max)
 select @s = 'SELECT * FROM mytable '
 Exec (@s)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out why that infinite loop was happening, that fixed it. With regards to dynamic SQL, as I said in my OP, I tried it before. Now I'm getting this: "Invalid object name '#results'."

Comment: Yes - you need to build up a string to execute that command using your @tblName variable. ie: exec ('select * from ' + @tblName)

Comment: I do that already, I'm getting the data from @tblname and putting into a temp table called #results, which I can't access apparently. I'm looking into using sp_executesql because that seems to be able to do what I want to do. Perhaps I'm not understanding you though.

Comment: It's still not working even if I use ##results instead of #results. I keep getting the same error.