# Stored procedure won't execute properly from java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure in T-SQL from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282441/dynamically-search-columns-for-given-table#comment14842545_11282441) which works perfectly when I execute it in SMSS. For example I have an animals table, and if I want to search for all columns that have the word "cat" in it I would do this:

```
EXEC SearchTable 'animals' 'cat'
```

That works perfectly, as I said. But when I execute the same thing from java, like so:

```
Statement statement = ProjectServer.dbConnection.createStatement();
String sql = "EXEC SearchTable '" + tblname + "' '" + searchTerm + "'";
System.out.println(sql);
ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

and tblname = animals and searchTerm = cat, it prints out this:

```
EXEC SearchTable 'animals' 'cat'
```

which is exactly what I do in SMSS. But I get this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'cat'.
```

I have no idea what's going on. I'm using JDK 7 with NetBeans 7.1.2 and SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma, aren't you?

The SQL should be EXEC SearchTable 'animals', 'cat'

Comment: Ah! Can't believe I missed that. Thanks. I'll accept an answer when I can. Apparently I'm not trusted enough to accept one so soon.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a comma

```
EXEC SearchTable 'animals', 'cat'
```

You can also specify the var names like so:

```
EXEC SearchTable 
   @tblname = 'animals', 
   @term = 'cat'
```

But.. still gotta have that comma.